# Python - how do i access keymap entries from the new tool system in custom keymap?

Tags: python

I can read keymap items from the windows manager. This code retrieves the keys in the 3D View, Object Mode section for example:

```
    wm = context.window_manager # Blender window manager
    keymaps_3DV = wm.keyconfigs.active.keymaps['Object Mode']
```

But this reads just the entries from the old tool system. The new tool system for the tool shelf are not to retrieve this way. They are not in the tuple.

What is the way to access this new builtin keys? Is this even possible?

[image]

Example script to test. Open the hello world panel to write the tuple content into the console:

```
import bpy


class PT_PT_PT_HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "View"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Hello world!", icon='WORLD')


        wm = context.window_manager # Blender window manager
        keymaps_3DV = wm.keyconfigs.active.keymaps['Object Mode']

        print(tuple(keymaps_3DV.keymap_items.keys()))



def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(PT_PT_PT_HelloWorldPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PT_PT_PT_HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

EDIT, the trouble in my case seems to be a custom keymap with some modifications. As a bravery test, i created a new keymap from the default blender keymap. And as a result i don't get any entries in the tuple at all with this code:

```
import bpy

keymap_tuple = bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.active.keymaps.keys()

print(keymap_tuple)
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "new tool system"? did you create this on your own?

Comment: No. The "new" tool system is the one that is used in the tool shelf. All the entries which are not in a category, but has now a own entry. 3d View Tool: Select Box, 3D View Tool: Select Circle etc.